# Laravel 5 always returning 200 OK - no matter what

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I realise this is going to be very, very vague. Basically I am sending AJAX requests with AngularJS (ngResource, or standard $http) to my backend. These requests are fine and receive the appropriate response, except for one small issue. I always get a 200 back, even if I see the Laravel stack trace, or send any sort of forced header.

```
return Response::make('message', 400);
```

I am completely out of ideas. Any wild guesses out there?

[image]

Comment: are you perhaps setting a header somewhere before your return line?

Comment: That was my first guess, but it really shouldn't be. I have also checked for white spaces, nothing of the sort. I literally have a route that does nothing else other than spit out the 400 status, still ends up as a 200.

Comment: Are you using any packages or Middlewear? Where are you using `return Response::make('message', 400);`?

Comment: Based on that though, where could I check for a premature header, prior to a route being loaded? Also yes to middleware, I have JWT running, but not on that specific route. Any way that could impact the app?

Comment: Try creating a new route for an index method of a new clean Controller, add the `return Response` code to the method and see if the same problem occurs.

Comment: Same result. I mean, even if I force a 500 error $this->doesntExist(), or a routeException it's still a 200. Baffled.

Comment: @Jeemusu don't give up on me :D Appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Well, if it happens on a clean controller that rules our your controllers. There isn't a lot I can do to help, your best bet is to go through the code step by step, make sure there isn't any whitespace at the start/end of your files, or your not outputting anything (echo, print_r, var_dump, dd()) before returning the response.

Comment: @Jeemusu Yea... Well there really shouldn't be. Needle in a haystack. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: @Dbrandt If your really stuck and it's not sensitive code, upload it somewhere and I will take a look.

Comment: so what was the solution? I have the same problem... already spent several hours to no avail

Comment: @QuinnDaley I honestly don't remember, I'm sorry I never posted the answer and this Project is long ago.

Comment: For me the problem was a linebreak before `<?php `. 
Removing the linebreak solved the problem

Comment: @QuinnDaley awesome that you figured it out, I don't think that was the issue for me - but should still help some people :)